# Transition of DIV background color not working

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have the below CSS for an overlay: an overlay which is shown when a sidebar is shown. I want that the background is applied in a slower time through transition but it is not working. Any suggestions?

```css
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: background 0.2s ease, padding 0.8s linear;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(192,192,192,0),rgba(192,192,192,1));
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show us how exactly you're starting the transition? As it is there's nothing to transition to/from.

Comment: you cannot have tansition on gradient and on display too .. try opacity instead

Comment: thats an overlay which cover the body, which is located under a sidebar

Comment: the background should really be a gradient or are you using it "define transition colors"? You should do as Temani says. change to `display: block` on show, but with `opacity: 0` then transition it to `opacity: 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot transition `display`. Use `opacity` and `visibility` to fake it.

http://jsfiddle.net/3zqorjt5/13/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code. you have to do it using animation.

```css
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(192,192,192,0),rgba(192,192,192,1));
    -webkit-animation: smooth 1s ease-in;
    -moz-animation: smooth 1s ease-in;
    -o-animation: smooth 1s ease-in;
    -ms-animation: smooth 1s ease-in;
    animation: smooth 1s ease-in;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@-webkit-keyframes smooth {
    0% { opacity: 0;}
    100% { opacity: 1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes smooth {
    0% { opacity: 0;}
    100% { opacity: 1;}
}

@-o-keyframes smooth {
    0% { opacity: 0;}
    100% { opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes smooth {
    0% { opacity: 0;}
    100% { opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: This code is beyond bloated. You do not need `cursor`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left`. There is also no need to be using a `keyframe` animation for something as simple as opacity, unless you are trying to delay it. A simple `transition` is all you need.

Comment: without adding a new class and a trigger, this is not possible. That's why i have written animation code. animation do it automatically without any trigger